# Vuetify Autocmplete with data loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I got 60k items in my autocomplete form, so I wanted to load it after user types 3 characters with only items that contains the given characters. Is there an option in autocomplete to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You should rather filter this amount of data on server side.

But it is doable in Vuetify. You can use `search-input.sync` and computed property for filtering items. Then you should clear your search value by input method

```html
  <v-autocomplete
    :value="value"
    :items="filterdItems"
    @input="clearSearch"
    :search-input.sync="search"
  />
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: null,
      search: "",
      items: [], // Your items
    };
  },
  computed: {
      filterdItems() {
          if (this.search.length < 2) return;
          return this.items.filter(item => item.startsWith(this.search))
      }
  }
  methods: {
    clearSearch() {
      this.search = '';
    },
  },
};
```